# Non-UI Ninepatch Border in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game and I have a group of objects in my scene that I want to encapsulate within an image that contains a border and a background, and have the border scale like a ninepatch.  The end result should look similar to a GUI with a border/background and objects inside.  The objects that I want inside the border are not part of the UI, and I'm not sure how to do a ninepatch outside of a UI canvas.  What's the best way for me to do this?

Comment: I have not heard of the term Ninepatch before, can you elaborate or provide a example of one?

Comment: It's a 9-sliced image in Unity, where the image can shrink and expand and the edges and corners will remain unscaled.